# Tables often need VACUUM in pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, playframework, ebean

I'm using the java Play! framework (2.4.2) with Ebean (2.0.0) and PostgreSQL (9.5)
While looking at the tables through pgAdmin, I often get the message that I should run a VACUUM ANALYZE operation and most of the time I get this result :

> DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet. There were 0
>   unused item pointers. Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins. 0 pages are
>   entirely empty. CPU 0.00s/0.00u sec elapsed 0.00 sec.
>   INFO:  « connected_object » : 1 pages parcourues sur 1,   contenant 26
>   lignes à conserver et 0 lignes à supprimer,   26 lignes dans
>   l'échantillon,   26 lignes totales estimées

=> The french part of the message says that all the lines where kept and none had to be deleted.

What are the possible causes of this ? What could I possibly do wrong with Ebean ?

Answer (score 2):

Just based on this information, my first guess would be that you have lots of transactions running that don't touch certain tables.  This means that pgAdmin may think something is needed but in fact that recommendation may be more pessimistic than it needs to be.

An immediate question would be whether running `VACUUM FREEZE` makes the warning go away.  If it does, then that is the problem (and at that point I would treat it as a false positive and just ignore it).